# how to create a flat file in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, formatting

how can I create a flat file in ruby?

Flat file is there each letter is placed at a specific column number in the file.

So for example if I am reading some values from the DB:

```
Name         Class
-------------------
one          A
two          English
three        Math
four         Science
```

and I want to make a flat file out of it where names are to be between columns 1 to 10 and class is to be between columns 20 to 30. How can I make that file? I know how to write to a file but don't know how to write to a file...with specified columns...?

I tried sprintf from Mladen Jablanović answer

```
C:\>ruby parse.rb
2342342423
SOMETHING
2342
01/03/2010SDSDFS
234234
sprintf on array        2342342423SOMETHING 2342      01/03/2010SDSDFS234234
```

Comment: Looks like it's working fine.  Do you still have an issue?  Maybe you need more space for each field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sprintf) (or its equivalent [`String#%`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/%25)) with padded fields:

```
"%-10s%-10s%-10s" % ['two', '', 'English']
#=> "two                 English   "
```

Comment: I was typing almost the exact words!

Comment: dope i think my array does not have `''`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use printf strings you can also use the ljust and rjust methods. If you have non-string data you may need to throw in a to_s call, though at that point printf may be better.

```
puts "#{name.ljust(10)} #{subject.ljust(10)}"
# => "Three      English"
```

If you find yourself needing more serious formatting and are familiar with formats from perl or fortran (I think) you might want to look into the [FormatR gem](http://formatr.rubyforge.org/doc), which lets you format like so and can deal with headers, footers, pages sizes and such. Here's a simple snippit:

```
@)      @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<       @#.##
num,    location,             toe_size
```

And results in

```
1)      Market                   3.50
```